Use training or testing set when calculating sample weights for evaluation?
I have an ml model that has been built from data that is not representative of the population class frequencies. The majority class is actually undersampled, and so it more frequent in the population than the data. When evaluating, I want to pass sample weights to sklearns metrics, like precision_score. I want to compensate for the fact that I've undersampled some classes, and get an idea of how the model would perform if applied to the population and the frequency classes observed there. Luckily, I have an estimate of the population frequencies from which to calculate my sample weights.
    # example frequencies but they sum to 1
    population_frequencies = {
         0: 0.8
         1: 0.2
    }
    # Get the frequencies in the data
    data_frequencies = df_train['target'].value_counts(normalize=True).to_dict()
    # the data frequencies show 0 is still majority class, but not to the extent observed in population. 
    # Let's say something like {0 : 0.6, 1 : 0.4}.

    # Calculate class weights
    eval_weights = {cls: population_frequencies[cls] / data_frequencies[cls]
                    for cls in data_frequencies}

    # Get the sample weights
    sample_weights = [evel_weights[label] for label in df_test['target']]

    # calculate the precision
    precision_score(y_pred, y_test, sample_weights=sample_weights)


So the aim of the sample weights is to account for the fact that class 0 has been undersampled in our data. When false positives occur, where 1 is predicted when the true class is 0, this is likely to happen at a greater rate when the model is applied to the population. The eval_weights describe the adjustment needed to have the data frequencies reflect their population equivalents.
My question is, I believe the data_frequencies used should only be derived from the value_counts of the training data, as using any portion of the information in the testing data would represent data leakage. Evaluation metrics should reflect how the model will perform on unseen data, and test set information must remain completely isolated until final evaluation. Is this correct? I can't find a reliable source to support using only the training set frequencies, but intuitively it makes sense to me.

The majority class is actually undersampled Why? Did you undersample it? Can you sample it correctly? If not, you may be interested in the King and Zeng paper discussed here.

Good question, we intentionally undersampled it because those events are abundant, but not interesting for the purpose of our model. Generating training data is the result of manual annotation, so we direct our annotators to classes that are the most pertinent for our project aim.

That sounds like the exact situation discussed in that King and Zeng paper.
